# Why I take a message for stack overflow in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, stack-overflow

```
 import Data.Vector hiding((++))
 import System.Environment 
 d = generate 1000000 (\z->case z of
                      0 -> 2
                      1 -> 3
                      2 -> 5
                      otherwise -> if odd z then (d ! (z-1)) +2 else (d ! (z-1)) + 4)
 algorithmA _ _  1 pt  = pt
 algorithmA t k n pt = let dk = d ! k
                       q = div n dk
                       r = mod n dk
                      in if r /=0 then
                            if q>dk then
                              algorithmA t (k+1) n pt
                            else (n:pt)
                         else
                             algorithmA (t+1) k q (dk:pt)

main = do
        args<-getArgs
        let n = read (args !! 0)
        if (floor(sqrt(fromInteger n))) > Data.Vector.last d  then error ("The square  root of number is greater than " ++ show (Data.Vector.last d))
     else
         print (algorithmA 0 0 n [])
```

When I compile the above program and give for example in the command line `test1 2222` I take the message "Stake space overflow: current size ... use +RTS -Ksize -RTS to increase ... ". But when I delete the if in the main function then the program works without problem. Also if I give the command `Data.Vector.last d`  in the ghci the value is calculated without problem. So why this message is printed? When I increase the stack size to 20M the program plays without problem.
The test1 is the name of executable.

Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you make `algorithmA` strict in `t` and `k`?

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: @DanielWagner I did the following algorithmA !t !k n pt = ... and I compiled with ghc -O2 -XBangPatterns test1.hs I run the program and I took the same message.

Comment: You don't need a vector when a simple function will do: define `d' 0 = 2 ; d' 1 = 3 ; d' z | odd z = 3*z-2 | otherwise = 3*z-1` and replace `d ! k` with `d' k`. And `algorithmA` doesn't appear to do anything substantive with its `t` parameter...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that your code is being too lazy when constructing `d`. Remember that `Data.Vector.Vector` is a *boxed* vector type - that is, it is represented internally as an array of pointers to heap objects (which are either values or unevaluated [thunks](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Rts/Storage/HeapObjects#Thunks)). So when you're populating `d` with `generate`, you are actually creating a vector of thunks. In your example, when the thunk at position `n` is accessed, it triggers the evaluation of thunks at positions `n-1` and `n-2`, which in turn triggers evaluation of thunks `n-3`, `n-4`, `n-5` and so on. So evaluating the last element causes the previous `1000000 - 1` elements to be evaluated, causing the stack to grow. This is why you get the stack overflow error.

An easy way to fix this without modifying your code [is to fully evaluate the whole vector before accessing the last element](https://gist.github.com/23Skidoo/5379967). In that case all thunks are evaluated in order and there is no stack overflow (since once a thunk has been evaluated, it's replaced with the value of the expression it represented, so when you're evaluating element `n` after having already evaluated elements `n-1` and `n-2`, only those two elements have to be accessed and the cascading evaluation of all previous thunks is not triggered):

```
import Control.DeepSeq (($!!))
...
let l = V.last $!! d
...
```

Testing:

```
$ ghc -O2 Test.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Test.hs, Test.o )
Linking Test ...
$ ./Test 2222    
[101,11,2]
```

Alternatively, you can [use unboxed vectors](https://gist.github.com/23Skidoo/5379892) (flat arrays of `Int`s):

```
d :: U.Vector Int
d = U.create $ do
  v <- M.new dSize
  go 0 v
    where
      dSize = 1000000
      go i v | i >= dSize = return v
             | otherwise = do
               val <- case i of
                 0 -> return 2
                 1 -> return 3
                 2 -> return 5
                 _ -> if odd i
                      then (+2) <$> (M.read v (i-1))
                      else (+4) <$> (M.read v (i-1))
               M.write v i val
               go (i+1) v
```

Comment: OK it worked, thanks for your answer. I would like if you can some more clarification. So if I understand the problem is that in my code the evaluation of the vector is done in reverse order forcing Haskell to use the stack and in your version , the vector is evaluated in the right order, is that so? Another question, why this does not happen when I write in ghci `last d` and it happens in the compiled version of the code?In addition the second solution, uses Ints not Intgers as the first solution. And it has some overflow errors for example test1 2222222222 gives [-1036372537,2].

Comment: @Dragno Yes, I changed it to use `Int`s. Changing back to `Integer`s is not hard: https://gist.github.com/23Skidoo/5379967

Comment: @Dragno `ghci` has a larger stack limit (512M) than compiled programs (8M). If you run `ghci` with `+RTS -K8M`, you'll see a stack overflow. For more on this, see this thread: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.haskell.glasgow.user/20360

Comment: @Dragno Yes, the solution was to change the order in which the elements of the vector are evaluated. Once a thunk has been evaluated, it's replaced with the value of the expression it represented, so when you're evaluating element `n` after having already evaluated elements `n-1` and `n-2`, only those two elements have to be accessed, which does not trigger cascading evaluation of all previous thunks.

Comment: I mean the second (unboxed) solution uses Ints not the first (boxed) version. If I understand well, the boxed version is polymorphic while the unboxed version can use only the so-called "primitive" types, and Integer is not primitive type. Am I right?

Comment: @Dragno Yes, you can only create unboxed vectors of types that are instances of the `Unbox` class. However, in this case you can easily fix the precision issue by changing `algorithmA` to work on `Integer`s: https://gist.github.com/23Skidoo/5379892 Both programs produce identical output for the input 2222222222 on my machine.